# Objective C - how to test private variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, tdd, bdd

How can I unit test the hidden variable *aVar* ?

```
// .h file    
@interface Class: NSObject

@end

// .m file    
@implementation Class{
 id aVar
}

@end
```

Comment: You unit test functionality, not variables. Test methods that make use of the private ivar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use KVC `[obj setValue:<value> forKey:<key>]` detail about KVC click [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html)

Comment: Or obviously `[obj valueForKey:<key>]` if you want to retrieve the value for the purposes of testing it.

Answer (score 5):

You could move your private variables to a [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW3), which keeps them private, but then create a -Private category that makes them public. For example.

```
// Class.h
@interface Class : NSObject
@end

// Class.m
@interface Class ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) id aVar;
@end

@implementation Class
@end

// Class+Private.h
@interface Class (Private)
@property (nonatomic, strong) id aVar;
@end

...
```

Then *only* import/compile Class+Private in your unit test target.

Comment: This almost gets there .... just wondering if there is a way to use a private **variable** over an _property_ ?

Comment: Clearly this generates an ivar called `_aVar`, not `aVar` (unless you add `@synthesize` statement accordingly). But I agree with you, Tim, that this is a better way of handling this. If you're going to be accessing this externally (even in tests), property is better mechanism (even if it's a private property).